# How do I enable Snappy codec support in a Spark cluster launched with Google Cloud Dataproc?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, snappy, google-cloud-dataproc

When attempting to read a Snappy compressed sequence file from a Spark cluster launched with [Google Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/), I am receiving the following warning:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: native snappy library not available: this version of libhadoop was built without snappy support.
```

What is the best way to enable Snappy codec support in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the launch image of Dataproc was built without Snappy support. I've opened a bug to get this fixed for the next image.

A workaround:

1. First create a small shell script that properly installs snappy and the native library support for it. For this we'll use the same native libraries bdutil uses. I called my script `setup-snappy.sh`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   pushd "$(mktemp -d)"
   apt-get install -q -y libsnappy1
   wget https://storage.googleapis.com/hadoop-native-dist/Hadoop_2.7.1-Linux-amd64-64.tar.gz
   tar zxvf Hadoop_2.7.1-Linux-amd64-64.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/hadoop/
   ```
2. Copy the new shell script to a GCS bucket you own. For demonstration purposes, let's assume the bucket is `dataproc-actions`:

   ```
   gsutil cp ./setup-snappy.sh gs://dataproc-actions/setup-snappy.sh
   ```
3. When starting a cluster, specify initialization actions:

   ```
   gcloud beta dataproc clusters create --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-actions/setup-snappy.sh mycluster
   ```

Comment: Thanks Angus, I can confirm this worked for us! By the way your last command has a small typo, it should be `gcloud beta dataproc clusters create --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-actions/setup-snappy.sh mycluster`

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this myself but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25438795/3877822) should solve your issue:

> For installing and configuring other system-level components bdutil supports an extension mechanism. A good example of extensions is the Spark extension bundled with bdutil: extensions/spark/spark_env.sh. When running bdutil extensions are added with the -e flag e.g., to deploy Spark with Hadoop:
>
> ./bdutil -e extensions/spark/spark_env.sh deploy